# OpenCV - Color correction

Tags: opencv, emgucv

Using OpenCV.

I have an RGB image, each value is a float.
I also have a standard color correction matrix 3x4.

What would be the **fastest** way to 'apply' this matrix over the image?

If you don't know color correction... This is a simple matrix operation.

If the Image looks like this (each pixel is 3 floats):

```
R G B
R G B
R G B
R G B
R G B
.
.
.
```

Then I would like to perform the following:

```
1 R G B     [ A1, A2, A3 ] 
1 R G B     [ R1, R2, R3 ]
1 R G B  *  [ G1, G2, G3 ]
1 R G B     [ B1, B2, B3 ]
1 R G B
.
.
.
```

All the values in the 3x4 matrix are constants.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have an rgb and you want an rgba back? Or an rgb you want the matrix to see as an rgba, with an rgb result? Normally, transform (I think) would give you the fastest multiply, as it is optimized. And even having to add in overhead to convert color CV_BGR2RGBA (plus copy 1.0 to the new alpha), it is still probably faster than anything other than hand written vectorized code.

Comment: 'A' is not Alpha channel, just a const to multiply by 1 so it is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by the rgb parts of the color correction matrix:

```
transform(imageIn,imageOut,M3x3);
```

Then add in the A channel correction:

```
add(imageOut,Scalar(A1,A2,A3),imageOut);
```

Read about transform at [opencv2refman](http://docs.opencv.org/opencv2refman.pdf)
where it implies you could use

```
transfrom(imageIn,imageOut,M4X3);
```

to get the same result in one step (it does dst(I) = mtx · [src(I);1], so helpful), avoiding having to add in the A components.
Your pardon, if that should be an M3X4. I am pretty dyslexic when it comes to matrix math, rows vs cols and which comes first.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, can you explain how this is exactly done as I'm not familiar with transform (is this CvMul?). I;m using an Image object, do I need to reshape it before preforming this operation?

Comment: I suspect cv::transform may be a good 'have you read -all- the documentation?' homework question, because it (to me) is hidden down below a bunch of RNG and SVD descriptions in the opencv2refman. I went back to read it again, and, hey lookout! It should do -exactly- what you want, with a 4X3 matrix.

Comment: @Gilad Details on how to get your image into a Mat is beyond the scope of your question, and very basic to openCV. You should accept this answer, as it is the fastest way to apply the color correction matrix to an image in openCV.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the values in your matrix are stored in RGB (by default OpenCV reads them in BGR mode), you can proceed with simple matrix multiplacation. You just have to create the right matrix containing the RGB values as you specified, i.e.
1,R,G,B
1,R,G,B, ..., with 1 line per pixel in the original image

Here is how you can do (in C++)

```
// say img is your original RGB matrix, transform is your transformation matrix

std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
// this extracts the R,G and B channels in single matrices
cv::split(img, channels);
// create a matrix on ones in floating point
cv::Mat oneMat = cv::Mat::ones(img.size(), CV_32F);
oneMat.push_front(channels);
// now channels is a vector containing 4 matrices of the same dimension as img
// you want to group those matrix into 1 single matrix of same dimension and 4 channels
// 1, R, G, B
cv::Mat rgbOne;
cv::merge(channels, rgbOne);
// Transform the row by col, 4 channel matrix rgbOne into a row*col, 4, single channel matrix prior to multiplication
cv::Mat reshaped = rgbOne.reshape(1, rgbOne.rows*rgbOne.cols);
// reshape is very fast as no allocation is required, check documentation

// now simply do the matrix multiplication
cv::Mat colorCorrectedImage = reshaped*transform;

// get back colorCorrectedImage to it's original dimensions
cv::Mat colorCoorectedReshaped = colorCorrectedImage.reshape(4, rgbOne.rows);
// note that you still have the extra channel of ones
// you can use split and merge functions as above to get rid of it and get your proper RGB image
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems there are quite allot of operations around rearranging the data so I have a feeling it will work very slow but I'll test it.

Comment: The longest operation should be the matrix multiplication, most of the other operations should be very quick. Reshape is O(1), split and merge involve copying values from one array to the other, but that's pretty fast. You have to check the maths but Bobbi's answer could do the job aswell, and should be faster since it operates directly on the data without having to modify it. And it's 2 lines of code! Had never used transform function before but will certainly keep it in mind.